# AWS Certificate Manager DNS Validation method not working with API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, dns, ssl-certificate, aws-certificate-manager

I am trying to create an SSL Certificate through the AWS PHP API by running the code below. The Certificate gets created, the problem is that the validation method the certificate uses is EMAIL and not DNS. I want to use the DNS validation method. Are there other parameters that have to be passed into the function? Any ideas here as to why my certificate is getting set to Email instead of DNS Validation?

```
$acm->requestCertificate([
    'DomainName' => "*.example.com",
    'SubjectAlternativeNames' => ["example.com"],
    'ValidationMethod' => 'DNS'
]);
```

Comment: This was introduced in 3.39.2 - 2017-11-22, do you have the latest SDK?

Comment: I didn't have the updated SDK. Is there a reason why the docs say the current API version is 2015-12-08 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Acm.AcmClient.html

Answer (score 1):

Dusan Bajic was correct. I needed to update to the latest SDK.